# Django Development Server

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

Just to give you some general context of what I am doing, I am currently in the process of making a mobile app for university students to notify them when a seat becomes available in a previously full course.

For my project architecture, my web service stack is setup very similar to a LAMP stack: Linode cloud ubuntu instance for linux OS, Apache2 for my HTTP Server, MySQL for my relational database management system, and Python for my programming language.

Also, to gather the data needed for my project, I am going to web-scrape via a python script with beautiful soup and selenium (for timed delays when loading the webpages), and plan on implementing cron jobs for minutely scrapes to continuously update my database on my LAMP Stack (specifically the number of seats available in a particular course) which will then send any updates of newly open seats to the mobile app (which I will code in the future, but have not gotten to yet).

I am having a LOT of trouble installing Django on my server. Thus far, I am able to starting up the Django development server in terminal, but when I try to access the project / default Django admin interface via web browser (every time I type in my servers IP address and port 8000 it refuses to connect). I have checked my firewall settings, followed all the online recommendations of inputting my server ip etc and am currently at a roadblock.

Comment: Why aren't you developing the app on your own computer? Upload it to the server when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the command you use to run the development server but try:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```